# Is it possible to validate a schema against nested objects?

Tags: jsonschema

This is not an array but nested objects that should have the same schema applied to them.

For example here is a config that will be validated:

```
myMaps:
  mapOne:
    requiredFieldA: 123
    requiredFieldB: "abc"
  mapTwo:
    requiredFieldA: 456
    requiredFieldB: "def"
```

The names `mapOne` and `mapTwo` are arbitrary. There could be any number of objects defined under `myMaps` and they could have any name.

Is it possible to apply a schema to all objects nested under `myMaps`? I have only seen examples of doing this sort of thing with arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the `additionalProperties` keyword, or with `patternProperties` if there is a specific format that the property names should conform to.

https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#additional-properties

Comment: I don't understand how I would use `additionalProperties` for my use case. Can you have `additionalProperties` reference  a subschema and have it apply to all objects nested in another object?